# Why can't I retrieve the data from my json file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

in order to learn AngularJS I'm doing a simple page for a company that will display products that will be read from a json file. I followed the tutorial on the angularjs website that did the same thing that I want to accomplish but when I do it by myself my browser tell me that I have two errors and I get this message `SyntaxError: Unexpected token a at Object.parse (native)`, I couldn't find the error anywhere.

This is my link to my [github profile](https://github.com/konsvasi/companySite/tree/productsDisplay), to the branch that I'm having trouble with. You can check out the `js/app.js` to see the controller which does the request and it will be displayed in the `partials/products.html` file. Feel free to see the other files too, the `services.js` was something that I tried but couldn't make it to work and it isn't used in the project so you can ignore it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even the github knows whats wrong: https://github.com/konsvasi/companySite/blob/productsDisplay/products/products.json malformed JSON, UNEXPECTED TOKEN is in 90% an malformed code

Comment: The error is even highlighted in red on github. What more do you need??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wrap the first *age* field in quotes: e.g. "age"

Comment: I think you are correct and that is what causes his problem. As a tip, you can check the syntax&integrity of your .json files using this site: http://json.parser.online.fr/